# Extract address portion of strings and geocode the address using javascript or react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, geocode

I've fetched some youtube video descriptions. The descriptions has address on them that looks like this :

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  
1. TRADITIONAL CAO LAU NOODLE FACTORY 

CAO LAU NOODLES: Soak the rice for 24 hours then grind it. Cook and stir until thick for 30 minutes.
Steam for 30 minutes. Roll to make it flat and steam. 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
2. Quán Cao Lầu Bá Lễ
ADDRESS: 49/3 Trần Hưng Đạo, Sơn Phong, Hội An, Quảng Nam 56000
OPENING TIME: 11AM - 8:30PM 

CAO LAU: In a bowl, add herbs, bean sprouts, cao lau noodles, char siu, chả ram, deep fried pork fat (tốp mỡ) then meat sauce.

PRICE: 35.000 VND / $1.51 USD 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
3. PHỞ SẮN FACTORY

 PHỞ SẮN: Grind the dried cassava into powder. Soak the cassava powder and water for 3 days and 3 nights then filter the water out, keeping the cassava powder. Whisk the cassava mixture in a pot for 30 minutes. Smooth mixture out. Place batter in a pressing machine. Dry noodles in the sun. After drying, cut into squares. 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
4. NHÀ HÀNG CỎ HỒNG

FRIED PHỞ SẮN: Pestle the pearl onions and place vegetables in hot water. Make the sauce with fish sauce, vinegar, msg, and coconut nectar. In a pan, add peanut oil. Fry the garlic, shrimp, and squid, add sugar, and then the vegetables. Add water and add a little starch. In another pan, deep-fry the pho san noodles. In a bowl, add the fried pho san, sauce, shrimp, squid, and top with spring onions.

PHỞ SẮN WITH FISH BROTH: Cook snakehead fish broth for 5 hours. Break the pho san into pieces and soak them in cold water for one minute. Place oil in a pot, add in pearl onions, garlic, tumeric, and the snakehead fish, and fry it for 10 minutes. Add in the pork. Pestle the fish. Add in the broth and cook
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
5. MÌ QUẢNG BÀ LÁNG
ADDRESS: Lê Thánh Tông street, An Phú ward, Tam Kỳ city, Quảng Nam Province

MÌ QUẢNG NOODLES: Soak the noodles and grind with a machine. Spread mixture on a flat surface and steam. When it’s cool, fold and cut it. 

MÌ QUẢNG: Add fresh mì quảng in the bowl. Add char siu meat sauce. Add char siu and shrimp. Top with the peanuts and spring onions. Add herbs and fresh vegetables.
```

Now, how do I select the address and geocode it to return x, y coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can get the address as follows:

```
const address = str.split('ADDRESS:')[1].split("\n")

console.log(address[0]) //  49/3 Trần Hưng Đạo, Sơn Phong, Hội An, Quảng Nam 56000
```

2. for getting the latitude, longitude of the address you will need to use a geolocating API such as [Geoapify](https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api) which can be used as follows:

```
import { API_KEY } from "./config";

 getLocationFromName = async function (countryName) {
    try {
      console.log(`fetching info for ${countryName}`);
      const countryData = await getJsonFromFetch(countryName);
      const latlng = [countryData.results[0].lat, countryData.results[0].lon];
      return latlng;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw new Error(
        `failed to get location for ${countryName}, ${e.message}`
      );
    }
  };

export const getJsonFromFetch = async function (name) {
  const url = `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${name}&format=json&apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
  console.log(url);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Comment: no problem, if my response answers your question then please mark it as the answer too. take care.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i've been to some rural and remote area these past few days. Can confirm, this works. Never knew split could be used that way. Thanks a lot!